# Create/Write files to external storage Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create and write to an external file in Android. My minimum SDK is 14 and my target SDK is 18. I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the correct place in my manifest. The following is the dection where I create and set the file path of the file to be created:

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        textView.setText("No external storage mounted");
    } else {
        File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(externalDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/tests-folder");
        dir.mkdir();
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            Log.i(null, "Does not exist"); // This gets printed - Why?      
        }
        File textFile = new File(dir, "test.txt");
        try {
            writeTextFile(textFile, "This is a test!");
            String text = readTextFile(textFile);
            textView.setText(text);
        } catch (IOException ex){
            textView.setText("Something went wrong!" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I keep getting the error 'Something went wrong!/storage/sdcard0/tests-folder/test.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). The writeTextFile() method is:

```
private void writeTextFile(File file, String text) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); // When I debug, it comes up until here and then returns with the exception
    writer.write(text);
    writer.close();
}
```

When it hits the first line in the writeTextFile() method, the code returns with an exception. My guess is that the files are not getting created. The log line 'Does not exist' gets printed. Why is this? I tried it both with my phone and emulator. I tried disconnecting my phone after installing and checked and was of no use.

If I modify the file path to create the file within the root folder of the external directory, I get an EACCES Permission denied error.

Comment: You could try with `dir.mkdirs();` which would create the whole path if it doesn't exist, instead of only the folder.

Comment: I tried with both - did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong - it looks like this particular file either corrupted something or triggered some weird bug. I created another activity with a different name in a different package within the same folder and that worked well enough (the code was copy pasted and so nothing changed at all). I then deleted this file and recreated it and it worked well enough. No idea why that happened but putting it out there just in case someone else runs into this in the future.

Prior to this, I created a separate project and typed out the same code and it worked. So I came back and tried doing a Project -> Clean through Eclipse but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not missing a `/` between the `sdcard` and the `0` in your path?

Comment: There is no '/' - sdcard0 is one term